# Prevent download of an angular website by unauthenticated users

Tags: angular, security, nginx, web-applications

have an app using angular and when deployed to a server, everyone can ofc download the source codes, obfuscated or not.

Yet, I would like to prevent user that are not authenticated to see the source code of the core application. Since right now, the login is made on the real app, they have access to everything.

I was planning on making a static page that serve as a portal, where user authenticate, and separated from the main app.

After login, you would receive an email with an url (would be hosted on the same server) and a token, that would bring you to the main app.

The server would verify the token (is this possible with nginx?) BEFORE serving any file from the main application.

Then, when an user is connected, since he is server the real app, but he is connected, I would not care if he as the source code access.

Is this secured enough? Is this doable using nginx?

Comment: No, users don't have access to the source code since you are supposed to serve the compiled app. Not the source code. https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: If you really want them to download bundled/modified code, maybe try sing nginx auth request module or write your own checks with lua module

Comment: @Ploppy having offuscated or minified wathever code server to client, will still in some way (with lot of struggle) allow user to revert engineer the app.